# Trying to edit/save file with root privilege fails with "Copying directly failed, see buffer '*tramp/sudo root @HOST*'

Tags: tramp, sudo, root

I have done this a ton of times in the past 10 months or so that I have been using Emacs (which I have quickly come to love, by the way) and never had a problem.  No clue what I changed or how, but now this does not work at all.  As far as I know, I didn't change anything.  Haven't edited my init.el or similar, haven't changed any configurations on my host machine.  No clue what's going on here.

I have the below in my init.el to open dired and then opening files from there to edit when I need to edit with privileges.

(require 'tramp)
(defun sudired ()
(interactive)
(dired "/sudo::/"))

That has served me well for months.  Now, I open dired and open a file (say /boot/config.txt), do my edits, C-x C-s, and I get the message "Copying directly failed, see buffer '*tramp/sudo root@HOST*' for details."  There buffer it mentions is empty.  My messages buffer has this:

Saving file /sudo:root@HOST:/boot/config.txt...
Renaming /sudo:root@HOST:/boot/config.txt to /sudo:root@HOST:/boot/config.txt~...done
Copying /tmp/tramp.eqRQkH.txt to /sudo:root@HOST:/boot/config.txt...
Copying directly failed, see buffer ‘*tramp/sudo root@HOST*’ for details.

I've searched around and found similar problems involving Tramp... Nothing that helps my issue though.  At least not that I can work out.

Same thing happens when I try to use C-x C-f and type out /sudo:root@HOST:/boot/config.txt, do my edits, and then C-x C-s.  I get those same error messages, etc.

Probably making a noob mistake here.  Someone school me please.

Comment: It's not you. `tramp-mode` has a bad bug. It has a couple of really bad bugs.

Comment: Michael was able to sort this out for me via email.  As I remember, the issue had to do with an out of place/bad argument to a cp command somewhere inside tramp.  It is/was a bug that had been fixed, so an update to tramp (and ultimately my version of emacs) solved my woes.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to say what's up. Please contact the Tramp tower via email to `tramp-devel@gnu.org`. Prepare traces with level 6 and send them with, the Tramp manual teaches you how to do this.